# How to display a div tag if any form errors exist in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I know how to do one off validations in angular. What I am looking to do is to display a warning at the top of the page if any errors exist in the below forms that were trying to submit. How do I accomplish this?

Is there a form.$errors? For if any error occurs on the page?

So can I do something like this?

```
<div id="errorInfoHeader" ng-show="formName.$errors">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track:

```
formName.$invalid
```

is what you're looking for.

```
<div id="errorInfoHeader" ng-show="formName.$invalid">
```

See this plunkr that demonstrates what you're trying to do:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9Ny58FY9rv74sxXryKmh?p=preview

Comment: Ok, question this sort of seems to work, but only after the form is declared. If the div tag is before the form. It doesn't execute. So how do I get it to execute.

Comment: In your controller, you can bind formName.$invalid to another variable on the scope. Then use that variable to show/hide your errorInfoHeader.

Comment: Found it I had a different controller declared in between

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$valid` like this:

```
<div id="errorInfoHeader" ng-show="formName.$valid">
```